# Consuming service WCF with self-signed cert from Windows Phone 7 err

Tags: silverlight, wcf, windows-phone-7, ssl-certificate

I wanted to switch my WCF service running on Azure from `http` to `https`, but when I try to consume service from Windows Phone 7 I get this err:

> There was no endpoint listening at https://xxxxx.cloudapp.net/MainService.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

I have created self-signed certificate with the same name as the service uri, then send the certificate to Windows Phone by email and installed it. But I keep getting this message, even from the emulator as well as the real phone.

Consuming services works both from WPF and desktop Silverlight applications.

WP config
ServiceReferences.ClientConfig

```
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IGEOService" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" />
            </binding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAccountService" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://xxxxx.cloudapp.net/MainService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IGEOService"
            contract="ServiceReference1.IGEOService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IGEOService" />
        <endpoint address="https://xxxxx.cloudapp.net/MainService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IAccountService"
            contract="ServiceReference1.IAccountService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IAccountService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

On server

clientaccesspolicy.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
<cross-domain-access>
<policy>
  <allow-from http-request-headers="SOAPAction">
      <domain uri="http://*" />
      <domain uri="https://*" />
  </allow-from>
  <grant-to>
    <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
  </grant-to>
</policy>
</cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

Service configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ServiceConfiguration serviceName="Diplomka" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration" osFamily="1" osVersion="*">
  <Role name="MainWFCRole">
    <Instances count="1" />
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
    <Certificates>
      <Certificate name="diplomka.cloudapp.net" thumbprint="539B9A0149DC1221F0F4ECA79BAD84073BF1D650" thumbprintAlgorithm="sha1" />
    </Certificates>
  </Role>
  <Role name="WebKlient">
    <Instances count="1" />
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" />
      </ConfigurationSettings>
    </Role> 
</ServiceConfiguration>
```

Serivce definiton

```
enter code here
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <ServiceDefinition name="Diplomka" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition">
 <WebRole name="MainWFCRole">
    <Sites>
     <Site name="Web">
       <Bindings>
         <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
       </Bindings>
      </Site>
      </Sites>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="https" port="443" certificate="diplomka.cloudapp.net" />
   </Endpoints>
    <Imports>
      <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
    </Imports>
    <LocalResources>
      <LocalStorage name="MainWFCRole.svclog" sizeInMB="1000" cleanOnRoleRecycle="false" />
    </LocalResources>
    <Certificates>
      <Certificate name="diplomka.cloudapp.net" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
    </Certificates>
  </WebRole>
  <WebRole name="WebKlient">
    <Sites>
      <Site name="Web">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
   </Sites>
   <Endpoints>
     <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="80" />
   </Endpoints>
    <Imports>
        <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
   </Imports>
 </WebRole>
```

web config

```
enter code here
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace>
      <listeners>
        <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
      name="AzureDiagnostics">
             <filter type="" />
        </add>
      </listeners>
</trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
 <system.serviceModel>
   <services>
     <service name="MainWFCRole.MainService" behaviorConfiguration="sb1">
       <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MainWFCRole.IGEOService" bindingConfiguration="binding1"/>
        <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MainWFCRole.IAccountService" bindingConfiguration="binding1"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
     <basicHttpBinding>
        <!--secure wcf by TransportWithMessageCredential security-->
        <binding name="binding1">
         <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
     </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="sb1">
          <!---->
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="MainWFCRole.AccountValidator,MainWFCRole"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
          <!--Enable https metadata exchange endpoint-->
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
 </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Is port 433 open on the firewall? Are you able to consume the service from a Silverlight or WPF app from a machine other than the one the service is running on? Have you verified with fiddler, wireshark or some other tool that the traffic is actually https?

Comment: I had this problem aswell. Remember to name the selfsigned certificate and give it the same name as the hostname. If host is localhost, then the certificate has to have the name localhost. Also remember when using the Emulator, u have to install the certificate everytime u restart the emulator.